# Setting a profile in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, jquery

Is there anyway that I can set up my profile in stackoverflow so when ever someone asks a question about `jQuery`, I will receive the question in my email so I can answer it?. Its easy rather than logging in and checking everytime.

Comment: you would get thousands of emails everyday

Comment: I know RSS is dead but it's still useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can go to you profile and setup a filter:

```
http://stackexchange.com/filters
```

and use "Just questions tagged with the " for the tag.
Set checkbox "Yes, send to" and in select choose "Every 15 minutes" (or as you wish)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.....I did create the filter.